# sublime text ruby test windows cannot find path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rspec, sublimetext, ruby-test

I am running Windows 7 and have installed the sublime text ruby test. I can run rspec spec/
fine from the command line, however when I try it from sublime text i get the following error:

I check the PATH variable and its the same in my command line.

--

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['bundle exec rspec spec\\models\\user_spec.rb']]
[dir: C:\Users\User1\Sites\sample_app]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI\Perl\site\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\bin]
```

Comment: You should refer this link [Sublime Text build: cannot find the file specified][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135313/sublime-text-build-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, instead of

```
 "cmd": ["cake", "sbuild"]
```

it should be

```
 "cmd": ["cake.cmd", "sbuild"]
```

Instead of modifying it just add:

```
 "windows":
 {
    "cmd": ["cake.cmd", "sbuild"]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using Sublime Text 3. I had the same problem and solved it as follows.

The cmd is passed as an array, while it should be a string. Maybe this worked in Sublime Text 2, but not in Sublime Text 3.

A solution that fixes the problem for me (Win 7, Sublime Text 3) is editing the code in run_ruby_test.py in the RubyTest folder.

Line 202: change this:

```
"cmd": [command],
```

to

```
"cmd": command,
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Where is that folder?

Comment: c:\Users\(User)\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\RubyTest\